# Preformat output CSV

Tags: linux, awk, sed, text-formatting

I have a script bash that converts this file "origin.txt"

```
cxx-yyy-zzz-999-111
2018-01-1T00:10:54.412Z
2018-01-5T00:01:19.447Z
1111-6b54-eeee-rrrr-tttt
2018-01-1T00:41:38.867Z
2018-01-5T01:14:55.744Z
1234456-1233-6666-mmmm-12123
2018-01-1T00:12:37.152Z
2018-01-5T00:12:44.307Z
```

to

```
cxx-yyy-zzz-999-111,2018-01-1T00:10:54.412Z,2018-01-5T00:01:19.447Z
1111-6b54-eeee-rrrr-tttt,2018-01-1T00:41:38.867Z,2018-01-5T01:14:55.744Z
1234456-1233-6666-mmmm-12123,2018-01-1T00:12:37.152Z,2018-01-5T00:12:44.307Z
```

How could I do it in bash with AWK?

Comment: So what's the *rule* being applied here? if you just want to take lines 3 at a time I'd use something like `paste -d, - - - < origin.txt` or (if you insist on awk) `awk '{ORS="\n"} NR%3 {ORS=","} 1' origin.txt`

Answer (score 4):

I have an awk script file named `tmp.awk` with the following contents

```
BEGIN {
   i=0
}
{
   if (i==0) {
      f1=$0
      i++
   } else if (i==1) {
      f2=$0
      i++
   } else {
      i=0
      print f1","f2","$0
   }
}
```

And a file `origin.txt` with the following contents

```
cxx-yyy-zzz-999-111
2018-01-1T00:10:54.412Z
2018-01-5T00:01:19.447Z
1111-6b54-eeee-rrrr-tttt
2018-01-1T00:41:38.867Z
2018-01-5T01:14:55.744Z
1234456-1233-6666-mmmm-12123
2018-01-1T00:12:37.152Z
2018-01-5T00:12:44.307Z
```

Here is my awk command and sample output.

```
zb@server ~ $ awk -f tmp.awk origin.txt 
cxx-yyy-zzz-999-111,2018-01-1T00:10:54.412Z,2018-01-5T00:01:19.447Z
1111-6b54-eeee-rrrr-tttt,2018-01-1T00:41:38.867Z,2018-01-5T01:14:55.744Z
1234456-1233-6666-mmmm-12123,2018-01-1T00:12:37.152Z,2018-01-5T00:12:44.307Z
```

Comment: thank you very much they gave me several ideas with their eternally grateful examples

Answer (score 4):

Using sed:

```
sed 'N;N;s/\n/,/g' origin.txt
```

Using awk:

```
awk '{ printf "%s", $0; if (NR % 3 == 0) print ""; else printf "," }'  origin.txt
```

Output:

```
cxx-yyy-zzz-999-111 2018-01-1T00:10:54.412Z 2018-01-5T00:01:19.447Z
1111-6b54-eeee-rrrr-tttt 2018-01-1T00:41:38.867Z 2018-01-5T01:14:55.744Z
1234456-1233-6666-mmmm-12123 2018-01-1T00:12:37.152Z 2018-01-5T00:12:44.307Z
```